# Changing style of element after click event of an LI

Tags: angular, angular-cli

as title mentions; I am trying to change the style of a li element after i click on it.

I have a UL of li elements populated by *ngFor directive. I followed another article where I use ngClass. The problem is that instead of changing the specific li that i click on all li elements are changed within the scope of the specified ul. I'm not really sure how to change the specified li that was clicked. When i click to inspect my webpage, all li elements have the same class label.

Possible solution: I was thinking what if I got the value of the li element on the click method. Then in another method I change the li element with the previous value that was discovered in the click method. How would I be able to do this?

Here is my current source code.

my view

```
<ul class="hobbyList">
    <li *ngFor="let hobby of hobbies"  (click)="onSelect(hobby)">
        <span [ngClass]="{show: clicked, hide: !clicked}" class="badge">{{hobby.HobbyName}}</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

my component

```
  onSelect(hobby: hobbyObj, event): void {
      this.clicked = !this.clicked;
  }
```

my css file

```
.hide{
    color:blue;
}
.show{
    color:black;
}
```

Comment: Instead of using a single `clicked` property at the class level, add a `clicked` property to each `hobby` object

Comment: I still need to figure out how to change the style of the hobby based off where the clicked property is true or false

Comment: Change the click binding to `(click)="onSelect(hobby, $event)` and the `event` property in your function should be populated

Comment: It could be something like `(click)="hobby.clicked = !hobby.clicked"` and `[ngClass]="{'show': hobby.clicked, 'hide': !hobby.clicked}"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the html file:

```
<ul class="hobbyList">
    <li *ngFor="let hobby of hobbies; let i = index" (click)="onSelect(i)">
        <span class="badge hide">{{hobby.HobbyName}}</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

In the ts file:

```
onSelect(i: number): void {
    var element = document.getElementsByclassName('badge')[i];
    element.classList.add("show");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It's advisable to avoid javascript style. preferable with Angular Way. Using @ViewChildren and Renderer2 Class.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2qtml4

Comment: Do you have any examples :)?

Comment: I did look at your example. I guess it just didn't encompass my example at all. Kind of harder to follow